# Find all the possible combinations of three string arrays to validate a provided slug

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to generate all the possible combinations of three string arrays (style, color, room type)... Given this 3 string arrays:

```
const stylesArray = ['modern'];
const colorsArray = ['blue', 'white'];
const typesArray = ['kitchen', 'living room', 'bedroom'];
```

The output array should contain the following values:

```
modern
blue
white
kitchen
living room
bedroom
modern-blue
modern-white
modern-kitchen
modern-living room
modern-bedroom
modern-blue-kitchen
modern-white-kitchen
...
```

And so on... the combinations are valid only in that given order (style, color, room type). And note that only one, or two of the elements of each array is also valid. I found some posts where you can combine all the three, but not with this last condition I just mentioned.

The goal here, is to be able to validate if the `slug` provided is a valid one based on those given values for each "category" (style, color, room type). But those values aren't hardcoded, those are dynamically pulled from an API (which doesn't matter for this purpose).

So, the one listed above are valid slugs, but this are not:

```
blue-modern
kitchen-blue
kitchen-modern-blue
```

Which is why I mentioned that the valid order is `style` -> `color` -> `type` (but not all the values are mandatory, it could be just one or two, and up to three, but always in that order)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To be able to answer, it would help to know a lot more about how to determine if a combination is invalid or valid. What rule do you apply to say that this combination is good, but this one is not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create an array of valid combinations like this:

```js
const stylesArray = ['modern'];
const colorsArray = ['blue', 'white'];
const typesArray = ['kitchen', 'living room', 'bedroom'];

stylesArray.push(null);
colorsArray.push(null);
typesArray.push(null);

var combinations = [];

stylesArray.forEach(style => {
  colorsArray.forEach(color => {
    combinations.push([style, color]);
    typesArray.forEach(type => {
      combinations.push([style, color, type]);
    });
  });
});

var validSlugs = combinations.map(comb => comb.filter(el => el).join('-'));

console.log(validSlugs);
```

I'm basically creating an array of combinations, where each element is an array of the three values (including possible `null`s), and then mapping it to strings.

Comment: Thank you very much @Aioros! You saved my day! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create `a tree` and then `traverse` in `BFS`

```js
const stylesArray = ["modern"];
const colorsArray = ["blue", "white"];
const typesArray = ["kitchen", "living room", "bedroom"];
const items = [
  {
    id: stylesArray[0],
    children: colorsArray.map((id) => ({
      id,
      children: typesArray,
    })),
  },
];
const traverse = (items, prefix = "", slugs = new Set()) => {
  if (Array.isArray(items)) {
    items.forEach((x) => traverse(x, prefix, slugs));
  } else if (typeof items === "object") {
    prefix && slugs.add(items.id);
    slugs.add(prefix + items.id);
    items.children.forEach((ch) => {
      traverse(ch, prefix + items.id + "-", slugs);
    });
  } else {
    items = items.replace(/\s+/, "-");
    prefix && slugs.add(items); //comment if u need induvidule kitchen, living room
    slugs.add(prefix + items);
  }
  return Array.from(slugs);
};
console.log(traverse(items).sort((x, y) => x.length - y.length));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @xdeepakv, I highly appreciate it! :)
It works, but I found the other solution easier to implement, because it's more direct.
Because the values I provided as example aren't hardcoded values, first I need to dynamically pull those from an API. And would make it harder to "manually" build the items tree.

Comment: both are same solution, this is less hardcoded. work for any tree type of data structure.

Comment: I have updated solution, u can check, writing minimal code.. it works same as above